# Word-wrap all text and fit div to size of a child?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="container">
    This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text.<br><br>
    <label>Input: <input type="text"></label>
</div>
```

I need the div to be the width of the `<label>` and the text to wrap.

Without the text, I can make **.container** inline-block so it fits to the label, but it will otherwise stretch with the text.

[image: How it should loook]

Is this possible?

Comment: @LcSalazar I just edited the question for the OP, they forgot to quote `<label>`...

Comment: do you want the `label` AND the `input` to be the same width as the text (ie `.container`)...?

Comment: .container should be inline-block that stretches with the label: <input>. The text should word break at this size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example uses CSS to accomplish this: `display: table-caption;` on the `div`, and `white-space: nowrap;` on the `label`.

Click the "Run code snippet" button below to see how it actually renders. (It's just HTML with embedded CSS; no JavaScript.)

```html
<div class="container" style="display: table-caption;">
 This is just some text. This is just some text. This is just some text.<br><br>
 <label style="white-space: nowrap;">Input: <input type="text"></label>
</div>
```